# Create a CFG for the following languages

Tags: context-free-grammar

I was just wondering if my CFG is correct for the first language.

The following languages are over the alphabet {a,b,c}

first language

{xcy | x and y are strings with the same number of a's}

My CFG

S -> AaASAaA | c | AcA

A -> AA | b | c | epsilon

second language

{a^ib^jc^k | i >= j + k}

in my class, we proved that the same language does not have a CFG if i=j=k, how is this different? Does this even have a CFG? If it does I can't think of any kind of cfg that produces that language, the only one I can think of just satisfies that the number of a's is more than or equal to the number of b's plus the number of c's, where order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CFG for the first language is correct, although I would prefer to write A unambiguously like this:

```
A -> epsilon | Ab | Ac
```

Second language:

```
S -> M | aS
M -> N | aMc
N -> epsilon | aNb
```

Note:  yes, this is a homework problem, but I don't think that providing then answer here ruins this particular learning experience.  Once you see it, you get it, and if you don't get it, you can bang your head against it for a long time without getting anywhere.